# Extracting values from a Bézier curve in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, curves

given a list of points I've created a Bézier curve, and now I would like to understand how to extract a "middle point" from a curve or get a list of points (not the input ones, the interpolated ones)

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please can you include a simple example of what you have done using Mathematica code we can copy and work with?

Comment: You should use the `BezierFunction[your_points][i]`, where `i` is parameter (in range 0-1) which is proportional to the path along your curve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8):

- Here we provided an example which indicate that we can not directly use `BezierFunction` or `BSplineFunction` since it is different to `BezierCurve`.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}};
a = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Dotted, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}];
b = ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pts[[1 ;; 4]]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow];
c = ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pts[[4 ;; 7]]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
d = ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pts[[1 ;; 7]]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
{Show[a, b, c, PlotRange -> All], Show[a, b, c, d, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]

The red one is `BezierFunction` and the yellow+green is the `BezierCurve`.

- `BezierCurve` can be draw as the piecewise function  of the `BezierFunction`. When the `Length` of the points is `4,3,2,1`, the `BezierCurve` or `BezierFunction` is the usual 3-degree Bezier curve, 2-degree parabola, `Line`,`Point` respectly. We see this as below. ( We can change the value of `k`, and since `BezierFunction` does not accepct one point, so maybe have some warning message )

```
Clear["Global`*"];
bezierFunction[pts_][t_] := 
  Module[{n = Length@pts}, 
   Sum[BernsteinBasis[n - 1, i - 1, t]*pts[[i]], {i, 1, n}]];

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 
    2}, {8, 1}, {10, 1}, {11, -2}, {13, 2}};
k = 11;
pts = pts[[1 ;; k]];
partitions = Partition[pts, UpTo@4, 3];
g1 = Graphics[{BezierCurve@partitions}];
g2 = Graphics[{ColorData[97] /@ Range@Length@partitions, 
     BezierCurve /@ partitions} // Thread];
g3 = ParametricPlot[
   Through@(BezierFunction /@ partitions)@t // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}];
g4 = ParametricPlot[
   Through@(bezierFunction /@ partitions)@t // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}];
GraphicsGrid[{{g1, g2}, {g3, g4}}]
```

[image]

- And on the contrary, we can set the degree of `BezierCurve` to fit the `BezierFunction` since the degree of `BezierFunction` is always equal to `n-1` where `n` is the `Length` of the points.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
bezierFunction[pts_][t_] := 
  Module[{n = Length@pts}, 
   Sum[BernsteinBasis[n - 1, i - 1, t]*pts[[i]], {i, 1, n}]];

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 
     0}, {7, 2}, {8, 1}, {10, 1}, {11, -2}, {13, 2}};
Graphics[BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> Length@pts]]
ParametricPlot[bezierFunction[pts]@t, {t, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pts]@t, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

- The `Arrow` and `Arrowheads` function give the correct position at all the cases,and to my suprise, the arrow move as the constant speed, that is, according to the arclength!!!

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 
    2}, {8, 1}, {10, 1}, {11, -2}, {13, 2}};
k = 11;
pts = pts[[1 ;; k]];
ani = Animate[
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{Medium, t}}], Arrow[BezierCurve[pts]]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 1], {t, 0, 1}, AnimationRate -> .1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["`*"]
pts={{0,0},{1,1},{2,-1},{3,0},{5,2},{6,-1},{7,3},{7,2},{8,1},{10,1},{11,2},{13,1},{15,2}};
nd=5;
p=Partition[pts,UpTo[nd+1],nd][[;;Ceiling[(Length@pts-1)/nd]]];
n=Length@p;
a=ListConvolve[{-1,1},Prepend[UnitStep[n t-Range[n-1]],1],-1,0];
b=MapIndexed[BernsteinBasis[Length@#1-1,Range[0,Length@#1-1],n t+1-#2[[1]]].#1&,p];
f[t_]=a.b;
Graphics@BezierCurve[pts,SplineDegree->nd]
ParametricPlot[f@t,{t,0,1}]
Simplify@f@t
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your excellence code.