# Driving along a Beziercurve with given velocity

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

In this model I try to describe the kinematics of a point moving along a beziercurve `b[u]` (bezier parameter 0<u<1) with prescribed velocity `v[u]`. The motion is described by timedependent bezierparameter `u[t]` and  angle of tangent `\[Psi] [t ]`

beziercurve(examplary):

```
b = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

simulating constant velocity

```
v=1&
sol = NDSolveValue [{
\[Psi]'[ t  ] ==v[u[t]]   b''[u[t]] . Cross[b'[u[t]]]/(b'[u[t]] . b'[u[t]])^(3/2),
u'[t] ==v[u[t]] {Cos[\[Psi] [t ]], Sin[\[Psi] [t ]]} . b'[u[t]]/b'[u[t]] . b'[u[t]], 
\[Psi][0] == 0, u[0] == 0,WhenEvent[u[t] == 1, "StopIntegration"] }, {\[Psi], u}, {t, 0,3  }  ]

T = sol[[1]]["Domain"][[1, -1]]
Plot[Through[sol[t]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, T }, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

model  works fine as expected.

But if I change the velocity starting with `v[0]==0`

```
v = Min[1, (#/.1)^2] &
```

NDSolve won't start anymore and returns `u[t]==0 and \[Psi][t]==0`!

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: `Min[1, 0.] == 0.`?

Comment: What is the form of the Bezier Curve `b[u]`? And we know that `BezierCurve` is difference from `BezierFunction`. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/251536/72111

Comment: With $v=0$ initially and $(u',\psi')=v * \text{(stuff)}$, the system starts at equilibrium. Thus $(u,\psi)=0$ is correct.

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry, I added the definition of the `BezierFunction`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your comment. The question still remains, what restrictions on `v[u]`  are necessary to leave the equilibrium ?